# Node.js cannot find an installed module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

After deploying my node.js app to another PC (in the dev machine worked perfectly) and installing all the dependencies manually, I get this error when I try to execute it:

```
    C:\Users\myself>node app.js
module.js:340
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'xmlhttprequest'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Keystroke\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\transports\index.js:5:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Keystroke\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\socket.js:5:18)
```

But if I run

```
npm ls -g
```

It returns the list of the globally installed modules, and it includes xmlhttprequest. Then why my app is unable to find it? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe it have to be installed locally?

Comment: @RoKie83 `npm ls` on that folder returns a list that does not contain it, so I think that is not the case

Comment: Please show us the code where you `require()` in `xmlhttprequest`.

Comment: @jfriend00 It is not my code, as you can see in the stack trace is the socket-io module the one who requires it

Comment: Hmmm, something seems off here.  I wonder why you need the `xmlhttprequest` module on the server.  I've never had to install that module on my server when using socket.io.

Comment: I don't know, but installing socket-io locally solved the problem

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The module probably needs to be **locally** installed for the project as well.

Do you have a package.json file? If so, run:

```
npm install --save xmlhttprequest
```

in your repo directory next time so when your switch machines, you can run `npm install` to retrieve all of the dependencies.

Some dependencies are not useful when they are globally installed on the machine.

Comment: A module can work either globally or locally.  If local, a different path must be used in requiring it, but it will work either way.

Comment: @eddyjs It worked! That surprised me, why does it matter if it is installed locally?

Comment: Usually, you should install dependencies globally if they are run from the command line, and locally if you want them to be "required" in the project. Installing locally means that they will be in the node_modules folder, which is the first place the `require` statement looks. As jfriend00 said, global installs have a different path, and you can technically find it but it's not worth the hassle of setting it up that way.

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean by

> installing all the dependencies manually?

usually, we will install the dependencies by `npm install --save` or `npm install --save-dev` and when I need to migrate to another enviroment, I just need to clone the source code and fire `npm install` from the root of the project, and it will do all the magic for me.

sometimes it will have problem if the package you are use is a c++ addon, it will failed to install that if the node version you are using is different with your dev enviroment and prod envirment, be careful. I usually use `nvm` for my node version manangement, `nvmw` for windows, that can save me lots of time.

Comment: I meant `npm install whatever -g`, because currently I'm installing from a custom script and I don't have the package.Jason. I'll take a look at nvm!